# Error applying virtual switch properties changes

Tags: hyper-v

I want Implement Kerio Control Scenario in Hyper-V(win 8.1), for this reason I need two NIC, Including Internal NIC and External NIC.

I created Internal NIC Successfully,but When I Created External NIC faced this Error.

> "Error applying Virtual Switch Properties Changes
>   Failed while adding Virtual Ethernet Switch Connection"

Comment: Add some details of Question along with any Use case if it is possible.

Comment: I want Implement Kerio Control Scenario in Hyper-V(win 8.1), for this reason I need two NIC, Including Internal NIC and External NIC.I created Internal NIC Successfully,but When I Created External NIC faced this Error.